# Can't deploy my pet Nodejs app to Heroku: remote: FATAL: Can't find meteor app

Tags: node.js, heroku, meteor, deployment

I am trying to deploy nodejs app to Heroku, using their instructions. Everything was super, but when finishing the process with command "git push heroku master" I have problem:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 215, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (145/145), done.
Writing objects: 100% (215/215), 5.67 MiB | 489.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 215 (delta 95), reused 129 (delta 59)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
**remote: FATAL: Can't find meteor app. Set METEOR_APP_DIR to the relative location of the meteor app within your repository if it's not in the root or 'app/' subdirectory.  (Tried /tmp/build_a40a06f857ebd0b9240550674cacfe69)
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.**
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to memos-hse.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/memos-hse.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/memos-hse.git'
```

I do not use any 'meteor app.'.
I tried manipulate with METEOR_APP_DIR but have no result.

Have you any ideas how to handle it?

Project: https://github.com/Saribeg/Memos

Comment: How  did you config `METEOR_APP_DIR`? Please add your tries (even if they failed).

Comment: I tried something like this:

heroku config:set METEOR_APP_DIR='/'   then 

heroku config:set METEOR_APP_DIR='/app' - 

Different dirs to test.

Comment: What if you use `./` or `./app` ? Maybe the `/` has been interpreted as root folder of the server and thus rejected

Comment: No, nothing helps. I deleted this app and create a new one using heroku site (https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<app-name>/deploy/github) and enable Automatic deploys from  github. This solve problem. Now every push to master will deploy a new version of app, It's pretty comfortable. ))) Thank you for attention!